# Android stop application from crushing when activity context no longer exists when custom adapter is being called

Tags: android

I have an activity that has a fragment with a listview, when the fragment is added to the activity it also makes a call to internet to fetch data upon which on completion of the call a callback interface is invoked. The problem is when internet call is taking long the user may back press to exit the activity but this crashes. Why? The activities' context no longer exists because it is passed to the custom adapter which is called in the callback interface and nullpointerException is thrown from the constructor of the adapter when initializing the layoutInflater. How best can i handle this? Thanks a lot, below is my code.

```
   ///This code is in the onCreateView of the fragment

        NetworkHelper<DisplayEvents> networkHelper = new NetworkHelper<DisplayEvents>(DisplayEvents.this, getActivity());
                networkHelper.fetchEvents();

                if(list != null && list.isEmpty())
                {
                    eventsGridView.setAdapter(eventsGridViewAdapter);
                }
                else
                {
                    loadingEvents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    networkHelper.fetchEvents();
                }


    ///Then the network callback in the same fragment is

    @Override
        public void onLoadEvents(List<EventModel> eventModels) {
            list = eventModels;
            loadingEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            eventsGridViewAdapter = new EventsGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), list);
            eventsGridView.setAdapter(eventsGridViewAdapter);
        }

// the context of the activity is passed to the eventsGridViewAdapter
 public EventsGridViewAdapter(Context context, List<EventModel> list)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

//application crushes here
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context, 400, 400);

    }
```

We can clearly see that if back is pressed no context exist by the time the networkHelper attempts to call the callback interface which in turn calls the adapter, please help out with this. the application keeps crushing

Comment: try this:    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

Comment: I think you should control onBackPressed to stop this process even though you can use application context instead getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: I cant cancel htttp call once it has started, using inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) i think the context is still referencing the activity which is long exited

Comment: Found the solution by using activity without the fragments